# Saving a Image from PictureBox to a database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

I was wondering how can I save a picture I choose from my computer using a browse File Dialog to a Database in visual basic.

I am using the following code to choose the image form my PC:

```
Private Sub btnBuscar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBuscar.Click

With OpenFileDialog1
    .CheckFileExists = True
    .ShowReadOnly = False
    .Filter = "All Files |*.*| Bitmap Files (*)|*.bmp;*.gif;*.jpg"
    .FilterIndex = 2

    If .ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then

        PictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(.FileName)

    End If

  End With

End Sub
```

From my form I am calling another class to create the object:

```
gestor.agregarMission(txtNombre.Text, txtTrip.Text, dtInicio.Value, numDuracionDia.Text, programa, txtDatos.Text, txtResul.Text, picture, txtNave.Text, cuerpo)
```

I need to construct an object Mission with some parameters including a Image, this is the constructor:

```
Public Sub agregarMission(pnombre As String, ptripulantes As String, pfechaLanz As Date, pduracion As Double, pprograma As String, pdescripcion As String, presultado As String, **pinsignia As Image**, pnave As String, pcuerpo As String)

Dim objMision As New Mision(pnombre, ptripulantes, pfechaLanz, pduracion, pprograma, pdescripcion, presultado, pinsignia, pnave, pcuerpo)
multiMision.registrarMission(objMision)

End Sub
```

What I can't seen to find is the equivalent for pictureBox.Image or wahetever so I can send it to the constructor.

In my SQL table the field type is Image, I've been told that the Image type is actually an array, so I don't know if I can convert it to String later and recover it later as the original type.

If anyone can give me a tip I would be very grateful!

Comment: what is wrong with `pinsignia As Image`? `Image` is an actual NET Type, so if you have a property such as `Insignia As Image` you should be fine.  As for the DB, store a byte array, the column type depends on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you pass the Image filename as a string into your `agregarMission`, you can use it to read the image, convert it to bytes and insert it. The PictureBox isn't needed unless you use it for something else.

```
Dim fiImage As FileInfo = New FileInfo(imageFilename)
Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(imageFilename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read)
Dim imgByteArray = New Byte((Convert.ToInt32(fiImage.Length)) - 1) {}
fs.Read(imgByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fiImage.Length))
fs.Close
```

Insert `imgByteArray` into your table field